# Exact binomial test using binom.test and qbinom, pbinom?

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

The below methodology is for a one-sided test.I am trying to use the two methods for obtaining the p-value where it should be the same in case of Binomial hypothesis testing. But I am receiving a slight difference in the values.

```
pi.H0 <- 0.65
n <- 121
alpha <- 0.05
pbar <- 87/121
( x.hi <- qbinom(1-alpha,size=n,prob=pi.H0) ) # upper critical value **##87**
( pi.hi <- pbinom(x.hi,size=n,prob=pi.H0,lower.tail=FALSE) ) # exact upper alpha **##0.043**
```

By using binom.test I have received a slight different pvalue.

```
binom.test(87,121,0.65,alternative = "greater",conf.level = 0.95)


Exact binomial test

data:  87 and 121
number of successes = 87, number of trials = 121, p-value = 0.06552
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.65
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.644058 1.000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.7190083
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference in p-values you find results from how you use the `pbinom()` function, specifically the `lower.tail = ...` argument.

The help file states the following:

```
lower.tail
logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x], otherwise, P[X > x].
```

So when you set the `lower.tail = FALSE` the resulting p-value will be the probability of $P(X>x)$ instead of $P(X \geq  x)$ which we get from the `binom.test()` function.

So either calculate the probability of $(P((X-1)>x)$, or calculate $1-P((N-X) \leq x)$.

In your example:
`( pi.hi <- pbinom(x.hi-1, size=n, prob=pi.H0, lower.tail=FALSE) )`